# Creating and using Multiple Filters/Searches using JTable or GlazedLists

Tags: java, jtable, filtering, glazedlists

I looked up how to use multiple filters on here with a regular table and the answers all pointed to [`GlazedLists`](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/). However, the answers didn't specify how to use it.  I was able to get one filter to work but do not know how to get more than one. 
For one filter I used:

```
  // nameE is a BasicEventList containing classes (name) which 
  // contain the table values
  TextFilterList filtered = new TextFilterList(nameE);
  JTextField filterEdit = filtered.getFilterEdit();

  // Inside the table value class (name) there is a filter for myName
  public void getFilterStrings(List baseList) {
      baseList.add(myName);
  }
```

Duplicating the code and creating another [`JTextField`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) does not work. I looked this problem up and it appears [`CompositeMatcherEditor`](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.7.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/matchers/CompositeMatcherEditor.html) may work.  The problem is I do not know how to implement this.

Also, I am using Eclipse. I downloaded [`GlazedLists`](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) 1.8.0 and dropped it into Eclipse. However, I can't use it. I have red squares all over (except for the source folder)! I even added the jar file.

I hope I have explained myself correctly. Please let me know if I need to expand.

My Pastebin: [Name](http://pastebin.org/47044), [Browser](http://pastebin.org/47045), [TableFormat](http://pastebin.org/47046), [TableModel](http://pastebin.org/47047)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextFilterList is deprecated - see the [javadocs](http://www.publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.5.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/migrationkit/swing/TextFilterList.html) - but that's a side issue.

There are several approaches you can use here - if you want really simple, then just wrap your filter list in another filter list:

```
EventList filtered = new FilterList(new FilterList(nameE, myFirstMatcherEditor), mySecondMatcherEditor);
```

A better way is to use multiple matcher editors to create a [CompositeMatcherEditor](http://www.publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.5.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/matchers/CompositeMatcherEditor.html):

```
EventList filtered = new FilterList(nameE, new CompositeMatcherEditor(myFirstMatcherEditor, mySecondMatcherEditor));
```

you can use setMode to control whether your editors are combined using AND or OR behavior.

Here's [Must Read info](http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/documentation/tutorial) on using filter lists.

The screencasts available [here](http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/) are also worth the few minutes investment.

Comment: The first option worked wonderfully. 

To make a third you would use: 

`EventList filtered = new FilterList(new FilterList(new FilterList(new FilterList(nameE, myFirstMatcherEditor), mySecondMatcherEditor), myLastMatcherEditor);`

 Is that correct? 

The second option gave me an error. 
`CompositeMatcherEditor is not defined`

Comment: Here's the API docs:  http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ - without question, CompositeMatcherEditor is the correct way to do this - stacking filter lists like you've done will work, but it's inefficient.

Comment: PS - your error message indicates that you just don't have the right package imports.  If you aren't sure about how to import the necessary package (ca.odell.glazedlists.matchers), let me know.  I *really* recommend that you look at the must read info I posted above - there is very good sample code in both that and the screencasts.

Comment: I had `ca.odell.glazedlists.*;` imported. 

The screenshots seem to be dead in the *Must Read Info*. Is the site broken on just my end or yours as well?

Comment: Right - you don't have the correct import.  You have to also import co.odell.glazedlists.matchers.*

The must read info link I posted doesn't have screen shots at all - just lots of insanely useful text.  If you are asking about the Screen*casts* (the second link I posted), those work just fine for me.

Comment: The packages were working I just had bad coding. 
http://pastebin.org/50808
Thanks a bunch! You were a huge help!